# Lotus Domino Unable to replicate with the server

Tags: ibm-domino

In my company I have two servers one is like abc and second one is xyz, both are in cluster. When my abc server is down it automatically route to xyz server, but now I am getting an error like unable to replicate with the server xyz and special database object cannot be located.

Comment: Typically the error means that there is a design element missing or corrupted. But your question is too broad to actually answer with any accuracy.

Comment: Dear Simon,I am asking that when my one server is going down than mail database automatically moves to another server,but now it's not working.Error is RRV bucket is corrupt.

Comment: "RRV bucket is corrupt" errors means non-recoverable corruption in your NSF. You need to restore from backups.

Answer (score 0):

As Simon stated in the comments, the error messages like "special database object cannot be located" or "RRV bucket is corrupt" are directly related to a cluster failover event.

Verify that all your mail database replicas (on server abc AND server xzy AND locally on the PC) are not damaged or corrupt. If one or more replicas give a "RRV bucket is corrupt" error, replace them with a new replica from a working instance or a backup.

If that does not fix your problem, please give more details like Server version, client version, output of "fixup" and "compact" on all database replicas, ...